# Java cannot find symbol

Tags: java, tcp, applet, client

I'm making a TCP Client in Applet mode and I get this strange error...

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\DanJavaGen\ClientApplet.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printStrackTrace()
location: class java.lang.Exception
e.printStrackTrace();
 ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

teh code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientApplet extends Applet {
public void init() {
Socket s = null;

try {
//s = new Socket(getParameter("host"), Integer.valueOf(getParameter("port")));
s = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
int buf = -1;
while ((buf = in.read()) != '.') {
System.out.print((char)buf);
}
}catch(Exception e) {
e.printStrackTrace();
}
finally {
try {
    s.close();
    } catch(IOException e)
    { }
}



}
}
```

What's the deal?

Comment: What is the actual subclass of Exception that is thrown?

Comment: You should try an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse, it would have caught something like this while you were writing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try printStackTrace instead of printStrackTrace (you have an extra r in there)

Answer (score 3):

replace: /`printStrackTrace`/ with /`printStackTrace`/ ( hint drop the **r** in Strack )

For future error, I'll tell you how to read this messages:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method printStrackTrace()
location: class java.lang.Exception
e.printStrackTrace();
 ^
1 error
```

**Cannot find symbol** : Means, that something you're trying to use doesn't exists, it could be a class , a variable or like in this case, a method.

**symbol**  : method printStrackTrace()** : It tells you what the problematic symbol is, in this case  a method named `printStrackTrace`

**location** where is that symbol suppose to be, in this case the class that should have the method is `java.lang.Exception` which belong to the java core classes.

```
e.printStrackTrace();
 ^
1 error
```

That tells you what was what you write that wasn't found. Should give you a good context. Most of the times the line where the error happen is included , so you can know what file and line number.

I hope this help you for future errors.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled printStackTrace

Answer (score 0):

e.printStackTrace and if uwant only message then use

System.out.println(e.getMessage());